# Setting focus of input text in a loop

Tags: javascript, jsf-2, focus

I need to set focus to an h:inputText which is in a component like this:

```
    <h:panelGroup id="bidView">
        <h:panelGroup rendered="#{some conditions}">            
            <h:outputText>
            Some text</h:outputText>                
            <p:inputText id="amountInput" value="#{bean.bidAmount}" />
            <h:commandButton value="Submit">
                <f:ajax listener="#{bean.submit(item)}" execute="@form" render="bidView "/>
            </h:commandButton>
        </h:panelGroup>
            <script>document.getElementById('amountInput').focus()</script>

    </h:panelGroup>
```

The input text that needs to get the focus is "amountInput." The javascript code I was thinking should do it is

```
<script>document.getElementById('amountInput').focus()
```

but it generates the following error: "Cannon call method 'focus' of null." What am I missing?

(I should add that bidView is rendered when the user clicks a Submit button next to each row inside a table. It, bidView, then shows up under that clicked row and allows the user to enter a number and have the server process it.)

Comment: Is your bidView wrapped is by a `<h:form>`? If yes, most probably all of the components would have that suffix in their ids. eg: <h:panelGroup id="j_idt272:bidView">. Can you check the firebug and make sure that the client side id is intact?

Comment: Yes, it is wrapped in a form. I gave it an id, "theform" and I'm trying to get to the component using theform:j_id_2l:19:bidView:amountInput (j_id_21 is also appended to each component, and 19 represents the place in the loop) but it's still null. Is that the right approach, to try and go down all the components? Doesn't JSF know how to find a named component?

Comment: That is weird. `document.getElementById('theform:j_id_2l:19:bidView:amountInput').focus()` should work. And AFAIK, this is a perfectly valid approach. About your other question, every component library has its own client side javascript API. Since you are using primefaces, I suggest you go through their client side API which might allow you to access components without their prefixes (I cannot tell you for sure since I have not used primefaces)

Comment: You mentioned of a loop. Does that mean there's one instance of bidView for each of the row? Cause if that is the case, you won't be able to hard code 19

Comment: @Nikhil: The `<h:panelGroup>` is not a `NamingContainer`, so the `bidView` should surely not appear in the client ID of the input component.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `document.getElementById()` expects the generated HTML client ID, not JSF component ID. You need to open the page in browser, do rightclick and *View Source* to see it yourself. Locate the generated HTML `<input>` element of `<p:inputText>` and use exactly its `id`. This ID is prepended with the component ID of every parent `NamingContainer` component such as `<h:form>`, `<h:dataTable>`, `<p:tabView>`, etc.

You seem to be using PrimeFaces. You can use the `p:component()` EL function to print the client ID of the given component ID.

```
<script>document.getElementById("#{p:component('amountInput')}").focus()</script>
```

An alternative, if you were not using PrimeFaces, is to bind the component to the view and use `UIComponent#getClientId()`.

```
<h:inputText id="amountInput" binding="#{amountInput}" value="#{bean.bidAmount}" />
...
<script>document.getElementById("#{amountInput.clientId}").focus()</script>
```

Coming back to PrimeFaces, are you aware of [the `<p:focus>` component](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/focus.jsf)? You could also use it as well.

```
<h:panelGroup id="bidView">
    <p:focus context="bidView" />
    ...
</h:panelGroup>
```

Comment: Thank you, BalusC. <script>document.getElementById("#{p:component('amountInput')}").focus()</script> works for me. I knew JSF2 is too elegant not to have something like this.

Comment: You could also use the PrimeFaces Javascript API: `PrimeFaces.focus(id,context)`